# Entity Framework Best Practice on catch exception

Tags: entity-framework, exception, ado.net

My Entity Framework will always targeting SQL Server.

So, in my program. What type of exception shall I catch?

[DataException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ?

and in DAL, is it good to throw the exception again after logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest multiple catch and log both.

In live environment its not recommended to throw error to client system, however you always need to throw the error.

So its your call how to do it.

If its live show a beautiful error to client that something went wrong and we are looking.